# Path system variable gets duplicated values when update via setx command

Tags: command-line, windows-7, system-variable, setx

My below .bat file add MySQL's bin directory to system PATH though the old PATH values get duplicated.

```
@echo off

set pathMySQL=C:\xampp\mysql
set p=%%

setx MYSQL_HOME "%pathMySQL%"
setx PATH "%p%MYSQL_HOME%p%\bin;%PATH%"
```

I expect the PATH value after this execution to be as below.

> **%MYSQL_HOME%\bin**;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\TortoiseSVN\bin

The actual value is as below - paths are repeated twice

> **%MYSQL_HOME%\bin**;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;

What I did wrong? How can I get over this?

Comment: Just use `setx PATH "%%MYSQL_HOME%%\bin;%PATH%"`

Answer (score 0):

The duplicated values in my system PATH are caused by how %PATH% is built up in Windows 7.

%PATH% = P1 + P2

P1 = PATH variable for machine

P2 = PATH variable for user

Clearing P2 to be empty will fix my issue.

Comment: ... except that that moves the user's PATH settings into the system variable, adversely affecting every other user on the machine.  Use `pathman` instead of `setx` if at all possible, or use a more powerful language (powershell, vbscript, or cscript would do) to manipulate the registry entries directly.

Comment: mod parent (*Harry Johnston) up.

Comment: @mnemotronic, how does clearing P2 move the user's path settings into the  system variable?